# Dynamic date parameters in tableau

Tags: dynamic, tableau-desktop

How to pass dynamic date parameters in tableau for which one parameter is 2022-01-01 and second parameter changes every quarter last day

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should create a Calculation Field that represents END QUARTER. There're different ways, for example:

[image]

where DATETRUNC() - the beginning of the current quarter (01/07/2022),
DATEADD('quarter', 1) - obviously add 1 quarter (01/07/2022)
And -1 day to find the of the current quarter.

And when you create a Parameter, you should refer to this Calculated Field:

[image]

Comment: But in this case how to perform incremental refresh. in my case my report needs to hold data from 2022-01-01 but needs to refresh every quarterly on incremental basis. for Q1 - 2022-01-01 TO 2022-03-30 and next refresh for Q2 alone. How to achieve this

Comment: use full refresh instead

Comment: Huge data, so cant use full refresh

Comment: maybe you should go to tableau community -- there will be much more expert help